# Does Android DownloadManager support resume broken downloads

Tags: java, android

We know that it had `android.app.DownloadManager` from android 2.3. While I want to know does `DownloadManager` support resume broken downloads and some example if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third sentence in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html): '*The download manager will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and system reboots.*' How hard was that to read? What sort of an example are you looking for?

Comment: I want to know downloadManager has the function like this.

Comment: what happens if the download ultimately fails?  is there a way to at least be notified of a failed download?

Comment: IIRC, download status is set to failed. Not sure if a notification is send on failure. See link to docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

DownloadManager in Android 2.3 has resume broken downloads feature. I got it from android source code DownloadThread.java:

`/**
     * Prepare the destination file to receive data.  If the file already exists, we'll set up
     * appropriately for resumption.
     */
    private void setupDestinationFile(State state, InnerState innerState)`